# Json in iOS5 showing error

Tags: ios, json, compiler-errors

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJSON", referenced from:

Objc-class-ref in JparseViewController.o

Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Ld /Users/mag1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Jparse-heknsvlbknssribatbwgkuefjoja/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Jparse.app/Jparse_armv7 armv7 i386
    cd "/Users/mag1/Documents/Xcode Projects/Jparse"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/mag1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Jparse-heknsvlbknssribatbwgkuefjoja/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/mag1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Jparse-heknsvlbknssribatbwgkuefjoja/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/mag1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Jparse-heknsvlbknssribatbwgkuefjoja/Build/Intermediates/Jparse.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Jparse.build/Objects-armv7/i386/Jparse.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/mag1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Jparse-heknsvlbknssribatbwgkuefjoja/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Jparse.app/Jparse_armv7

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJSON", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in JparseViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I got JSON framework files from downloaded example. The examples are working perfectly, but my project showing above errors.

Comment: this problem is coming mainly when your class are not copying in right way.then delete old one and copy again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386`

The above error occurs in the following situation:

1. You were trying to run your application in the iPhone/iPad Simulator
2. The library was only built to run on the physical devices, and does not support being run in the Simulator.

To resolve this, you either need to add `i386` to the Valid Architectures of the SBJSON library build target, or test your application using a physical device.

Comment: How to add i386 to valid architectures of the SBJSON library?I just copied and paste the JSON framework files from other example only..is that any prob?

Comment: @darvidsOn Thank you so much....Its worked a little for me.problem is I didnt had a JSON updated framework with ARC..But now i cleared my Issues.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't add the SBJSON.m file to your target. Check the properties panel for this file, and there should be a checkbox indicating which target it is assigned to. You may have simply forgotten to copy SBJSON.m into your project at all.

Answer (score 2):

go to *Projectapp* -> *Buildphases* -> *compileSources*

here to add all .m files of JSON    with + icon. problem will be resolved